# Prove the Radical of an Ideal is an Ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I am given that $R$ is a commutative ring, $A$ is an ideal of $R$, and $N(A)=\{x\in R\,|\,x^n\in A$ for some $n\}$.

I am studying with a group for our comprehensive exam and this problem has us stuck for two reasons.

FIRST - We decided to assume $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ even though this restriction was not given. We decided $n\ne 0$ because then $x^0=1$ and we are not guaranteed unity. We also decided $n\notin\mathbb{Z}^-$ because $x^{-1}$ has no meaning if there are no multiplicative inverses. Is this a valid argument?

SECOND - We want to assume $x,\,y\in N(A)$ which means $x^m,\,y^n\in A$ and use the binomial theorem to expand $(x-y)^n$ which we have already proved is valid in a commutative ring and show that each term is in A so $x-y$ is in $N(A)$. The biggest problem is how to approach the $-y$ if we are not guaranteed unity. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what you mean by “how to approach the $-y$”?

Comment: In general the binomial expansion would yield $(x+y)^{m+n}=x^{m+n}+\Sigma_{i=1}^{m+n-1}x^{m+n-1-i}y^i+y^{m+n}$. However if I am expanding $(x-y)^{m+n}$ I get $x^{m+n}+\Sigma_{i=1}^{m+n-1}{m+n-1\choose i}x^{m+n-1-i}(-y)^i+(-y)^{m+n}$. I know $y^m\in A$ but cannot conclude any information about $(-y)^m$ and cannot write $(-1)y^m$ because I am not guaranteed unity.

Comment: Let’s see: I claim that $(-x)^n$ is $x^n$ or $-x^n$, depending on whether $n$ is even or odd. For, $(-a)b=-(ab)$, as you easily see, and from this you see that $(-x)(-x)=x^2$.

Comment: Wow ... so in my usual fashion I was overthinking a little too much. Grazie mille!

Comment: @Lubin Could you please consider posting a variation of that as a solution? The question has now been asked more than once, and now refers to this one, but nobody has solutions... Thanks

Comment: All right, @rschwieb, I hope the answer below suffices.

Comment: @Lubin Yes it does, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have everything else, so here’s one approach to the question of why $x\in N(A)$ implies that $-x\in N(A)$.

Since $(-a)b +ab =0b=0$, we see that $(-a)b=-(ab)$, and so $(-x)^n=x^n$ if $n>0$ is even, and it’s $-x^n$ if $n$ is odd. In either case, if $x^n\in A$, then $(-x)^n\in A$, so that $x\in N(A)\Longrightarrow-x\in N(A)$.